# Как правильно: "взять на охрану" или "взять под охрану"?

Tags: синтаксис, предлоги

Kак правильно написать: "взять **на** охрану" или "взять **под** охрану"?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **взять под охрану.**

Вы хотите **поставить квартиру на охрану**?  Тогда вы можете обратиться в наше  предприятие и заключить договор. После этого ваша квартира **будет взята под охрану.**

Из словаря:

**Предлог НА** 6. кого-что. **Указывает на целевое назначение** предмета, **действия**. Отрез на пальто. Разрешение на проезд. Билет на самолёт. Отдать ребёнка на воспитание. Наряд на погрузку. Просить на пропитание. Учиться на инженера.

**Предлог ПОД** 2. (с глаг.: **взять**, отдать, попасть и т.п.). Обозначает **состояние, положение в которое ставят кого-, что-л**. или поставлен кто-, что-л. Взять под контроль. **Взять под стражу**. Отдать под суд.

ОХРАНА, -ы; ж. 1. к Охранять. О. лесов. О. порядка. О. труда. **Находиться, быть под охраной кого-, чего-л**

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: "поставить на охрану" и "взять под охрану".

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

**Квартиру можно поставить на охрану, даже если нет городского телефона**. [Ирина Леневская. Пока вы на даче или в отпуске: Защищаем квартиру от воров // Комсомольская правда]

**Территория, которую собирается взять под охрану МВД, довольна обширна.** [Роман Ветров. Олимпиаду в Сочи защитят стокилометровым барьером // Известия, 2012.09.17]